# What is the basic structure of the dist directory which is made into a .war file for Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

What is the ideal way to create the directory structure when preparing a dist directory to be made into a .war file?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. The internal structure of a WAR is hard specified by Servlet API spec. You cannot change this. Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: Yeah that is what I meant.  I had not realized there was a hard specification, which is what I was hoping for.  Is there a link to that?

Comment: At least, where the web.xml, libs and classes should end up. The remnant of public webcontent (jsps, images, css, scripts, etc) is up to you and in essence *unrelated* to WARs, Java and Tomcat, but more related to webdevelopment in general. A dozen questions have been asked about this before.

Comment: Coming back to this question after reading your newer questions: in Eclipse for Java EE you just have to create a *Dynamic Web Project*. This will give you the new rightclick option on the project: *Export > WAR*. No need to fiddle with Ant. I'd warmly recommend to read the *Coreservlets.com* tutorials which is linked at bottom of our Servlets info page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info It covers getting started with Eclipse+Tomcat as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In more complicated projects, I've been known to have a webapp directory in source like this:

```
my-webapp/
my-webapp/WEB-INF/
my-webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
my-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/
my-webapp/WEB-INF/classes/
my-webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/my.jsp
my-webapp/WEB-INF/tld/my.tld
```

Then, [using Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html), I make a temporary staging directory and use it to build the war:

```
<mkdir dir="${staging.dir}"/>
<copy todir="${staging.dir}">
  <fileset dir="${src.dir}/my-webapp" includes="**/*"/>
</copy>

<war destfile="my-webapp.war" webxml="${staging.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
  <fileset dir="${staging.dir}" includes="**/*"/>
  <classes dir="${build.dir}"/>
  <lib dir="${lib.dir}"/>
</war>
```

However, if your project is simpler (no JSPs, resources, etc.), you might be able to just get away without a defined webapp directory in your source. You could just have your web.xml somewhere appropriate in your source tree, point the `<war>` task to it, and specify your class/lib directories accordingly.

---

With regard to your clarifications in the comments, Tomcat (and most containers) expect a structure similar to the following:

```
my-webapp/WEB-INF/
my-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/     (for jar files)
my-webapp/WEB-INF/classes/ (for class files)
my-webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml  (deployment descriptor)
```

The Tomcat documentation **[section on Deployment](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html)** has a pretty good explanation of this stuff, too.

**Notable:** anything you put under `WEB-INF` will not be accessible directly (e.g. via a URL). Example:

- If you put JSP files in `my-webapp/jsp`, you will be able to access them directly at, for example, http://example.com/my-webapp/my.jsp
- If you put JSP files in `my-webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`, you will not be able to access them at the URL in the previous bullet. You would need to provide a way to get to them, for example, by forwarding to them from within a Servlet.

I prefer my JSP files to be in WEB-INF, since I treat them as views in an MVC structure, and have my controllers (Servlets) dictate how they're accessed and rendered.

Comment: In your example, the my-webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/ directory is more of a general "web-file" directory which would contain css, js, and other similar things, correct?

Comment: Correct. You can do pretty much whatever you want with the directory structure and your own resources. You could have your `jsp` directory right underneath `my-webapp` if you want to expose them directly. Static resources might also live at the top level in `css` or `js` directories. It's really up to how you want to do it; just make sure you have the basic structure in the second code snippet of my answer.